# ordering and concatinating two arrays based on one column elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have a big array of data with the shape of `(24000, 5)`. I gave this array as an input to a code but the code shuffled and changed fourth columns and only the last column is intact. What is the fastest way that I can find the similar elements in the last column and stick the correspondence rows in the produced column with the old one and make a new array?

For example the **input array** looks like this:

```
25.463 -10.249 -0.211  0.912 0.432
24.910 -09.089  0.722 -0.304 0.391
25.719 -10.522 -0.639 -0.002 0.638
24.022 -10.098  0.028 -0.007 1.921
```

output array is similar to:

```
230.1 321.9 -0.311 -0.010 1.921
349.6 301.2  0.740 -0.309 0.391
189.9 321.9 -0.220  0.920 0.432
259.4 292.8 -0.641  0.000 0.638
```

Final result should be like this:

```
25.463 -10.249 -0.211  0.912 189.9 321.9 -0.220  0.920 0.432
24.910 -09.089  0.722 -0.304 349.6 301.2  0.740 -0.309 0.391
25.719 -10.522 -0.639 -0.002 259.4 292.8 -0.641  0.000 0.638
24.022 -10.098  0.028 -0.007 230.1 321.9 -0.311 -0.010 1.921
```

Comment: You used a pandas tag...  So if these are pandas dataframes, just do a standard merge with the last column of each dataset as the key.  Just make sure keys are unique (and same dtype!) or else create one that is.  Merging on floats here is not ideal, but may be OK, just check that you get a one to one merge at the end.

Comment: @SaulloCastro well I want a one to one correspondence and I think the precision of the numbers in the column is enough to give satisfy this condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argsort()` to sort the last column of both arrays and then combine them using `numpy.hstack()`.

The `orig_order` is used to return the concatenated array to the original order...

```
import numpy as np

as1 = np.argsort(a1[:,-1])
orig_order = np.argsort(as1)
as2 = np.argsort(a2[:,-1])

ans = np.hstack((a1[as1][:,:-1], a2[as2]))[orig_order]
```